# Spliting GROUP BY results into different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have a column containing date ranges and the number of days passed associated to a specific `ID` (one to many), based on the number of records associated to it, I want those results split into columns instead of individual rows, so from this:

```
id_hr  dd beg          end
----------------------------------------
1      10 05/01/2019   15/01/2019
1      5  03/02/2019   08/02/2019
2      8  07/03/2019   15/03/2019
```

Could become this:

```
id_hr  dd beg          end        dd beg          end
--------------------------------- ---------------------
1      10 05/01/2019   15/01/2019 5  03/02/2019   08/02/2019
2      8  07/03/2019   15/03/2019
```

I did the same in a worksheet (pivot table) but the table became as slow as it could get, so I'm looking for a more friendly approach in SQL, I did a CTE which number the associated rows and then select each one and display them in new columns.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT PER_PRO, ID_HR, NOM_INC, rut_dv, dias_dur, INI, FIN,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID_HR ORDER BY SUBIDO) AS RN
   FROM dbo.inf_vac WHERE PER_PRO = 201902
)
SELECT ID_HR, NOM_INC, rut_dv,
    (case when rn = 1 then DIAS_DUR end) as DIAS_DUR1,
    (case when rn = 1 then INI end) as INI1,
    (case when rn = 1 then FIN end) as FIN1,

    (case when rn = 2 then DIAS_DUR end) as DIAS_DUR2,
    (case when rn = 2 then INI end) as INI2,
    (case when rn = 2 then FIN end) as FIN2,

    (case when rn = 3 then DIAS_DUR end) as DIAS_DUR3,
    (case when rn = 3 then INI end) as INI3,
    (case when rn = 3 then FIN end) as FIN3
FROM CTE
```

Which gets me each column on where it should be but not grouped. Using GROUP BY displays an error on the CTE select.

```
rn id_hr  dd    beg          end        dd    beg          end
----------------------------------- ------------------------
1  1      10   05/01/2019   15/01/2019 NULL  NULL         NULL
2  1      NULL NULL         NULL       5     03/02/2019   08/02/2019
1  2      8    07/03/2019   15/03/2019 NULL  NULL         NULL
```

Is there any way to group them on the second select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have additional columns in the result set that are not in the query.  However, this should work:

```
SELECT ID_HR,
       max(case when rn = 1 then DIAS_DUR end) as DIAS_DUR1,
       max(case when rn = 1 then INI end) as INI1,
       max(case when rn = 1 then FIN end) as FIN1,

       max(case when rn = 2 then DIAS_DUR end) as DIAS_DUR2,
       max(case when rn = 2 then INI end) as INI2,
       max(case when rn = 2 then FIN end) as FIN2,

       max(case when rn = 3 then DIAS_DUR end) as DIAS_DUR3,
       max(case when rn = 3 then INI end) as INI3,
       max(case when rn = 3 then FIN end) as FIN3
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ID_HR;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can GROUP BY all the non-CASE columns, and apply MAX to each of the CASE-expression columns.